# nodejs, How to call/pass response from other function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have problem with http.createServer response.

I have function onRequest that parse body from user POST and pass it into my function. I would like to send response to client after my function finish query, but I am not able to pass response to my function because it is undefined inside anonymous function.

```
function onRequest(request, response){
    console.log("Request received.");
    if (request.method == 'POST'){
        var body =' ';
        request.on('data', function(data){
            body += data;
        });

        request.on('end', function(){
           var as = JSON.parse(body); 
           spatial_index_query(as['x'], as['y'], response);
        });
    }
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8013, '0.0.0.0');
```

My function

```
function spatial_index_query(x, y, res) { 
    db.get("Select id from spatial_index where minX < ? AND minY < ? AND maxX > ? AND maxY > ?",[x, y, x, y], 
        function(err, rows, res){
           response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
           response.write('it works');
           response.end();
        };
```

It does not work.

Now If I would try to pass response to normal function like this

```
function test(response){
    console.log(response);
};
```

It works, but If I am trying to pass response to function that has anonymous function inside then it turns out that response is Undefined.

What is the proper way of using response in this kind of situation?

I could change my function to something like this

```
function spatial_index_query(x, y) { 
    db.get("Select id from spatial_index where minX < ? AND minY < ? AND maxX > ? AND maxY > ?",[x, y, x, y], 
        function(err, rows){
             return 'it works'
             // how to call response now?
        };
```

but I have no idea how to call response now.

I was also trying to create result() function inside onRequest function, that I could call from my function after query and pass result, but it would not work because result() is not visible outside of onRequest function.

**EDIT**
I had typo in my function, res instead response. Fixed function:

```
function spatial_index_query(x, y, response) { 
    db.get("Select id from spatial_index where minX < ? AND minY < ? AND maxX > ? AND maxY > ?",[x, y, x, y], 
        function(err, rows){
           response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
           response.write('it works');
           response.end();
        };
```

Comment: You argument is named `res` not `response` (`function spatial_index_query(x, y, res)`) , so you need to either name it `response` or write `res.writeHead`, ...

Comment: You should put the answer in the answer section (so I can vote for it) instead of editing the question...

Answer (score 0):

I had typo in my function, res instead response. Fixed function:

```
function spatial_index_query(x, y, response) { 
db.get("Select id from spatial_index where minX < ? AND minY < ? AND maxX > ? AND maxY > ?",[x, y, x, y], 
    function(err, rows){
       response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
       response.write('it works');
       response.end();
    };
```